# how to see the result of if else on SASS in the page

Tags: html, css, sass

I just want to know what to put in my HTML file to see the result of if else in SASS (it compiled successfully with no errors).

```
$theme: "dark";

@if $theme == "dark" {
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
} @else {
    background-color: white;
    color: #444;
}
```

Comment: You should have a dark theme based on your code. You dont need to put anything in your HTML, you have already set dark as the variable